# Mask equivalent in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am labeling points in a regression and want to "mask" the labels so they are easy to read when they intersect the line. ArcGIS has a function for this called [masking](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-masking.htm). Simple masking is essentially adding a white background (or shadow/mask) to text. I have looked over the ggplot text [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html) and it seems the ggplot way of fixing this would be to use geom_label, but I find that a bit clunky looking. I am trying to make the area I highlighted with red pen on

[image: this figure]

look a bit nicer.
Sample:

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:10,], aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, color="black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(mtcars)[1:10]),hjust=.5, vjust=-.4)#mask text?
```

Solution:

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:10,], aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, color="black") +
  geom_shadowtext(aes(label=rownames(mtcars)[1:10]),hjust=.5, vjust=-.4,
                  col="black", bg.color="white", cex=4, r=2)
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `ggrepel` package?

Comment: It would be nice if you could give the sample data and code to generate this plot. Thanks.

Comment: @r2evans something like this: ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, color="black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(mtcars)),hjust=.5, vjust=-.4)  #mask text?

Comment: @S.Confluentus: try `shadowtext` package? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52808472/786542

Comment: `m <- mtcars[1:10, ]; ggplot(m, aes(mpg, disp)) + stat_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) + theme_classic() + geom_label(aes(label = rownames(m)), nudge_y = 10, label.size = NA) + geom_point()`

Comment: Code and data don't always show well in comments, and comments can be skipped by readers or hidden by the SE interface. Would you please [edit] your question and add that code (and sample data)?

Comment: @rawr I thought of this but was hoping there was a nice way for the line to kind of pass through a label like the "Merc 230" label by getting a little closer to it.