# Plotting one point with conditions in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This may seems weird. But I want to plot exactly 1 point in the middle of the plot. It's not a dataset; just one point, with the following conditions:

- a `%` shape instead of normal circle shape
- color red but outline blue

I make a desire output:
[image]

I like using base R function, but ggplot2 suggestion will be appreciated too. ( but when I tried with `ggplot`, the input needs to be a dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R plots: Is there any way to draw border, shadow or buffer around text labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631216/r-plots-is-there-any-way-to-draw-border-shadow-or-buffer-around-text-labels)

Comment: @RémiCoulaud That's smart! I never thought of setting the `%` as a text rather than a symbol! So yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find how to draw the text with `shadowtext` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631216/r-plots-is-there-any-way-to-draw-border-shadow-or-buffer-around-text-labels/39002911) :

To make a plot without anything :

```
par(mfrow= c(1, 1),
    pty = "s")
plot(0, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "",  xaxt="n", yaxt = "n")


shadowtext(1, 0, labels = "%", col = "red", bg = "blue", cex = 3)
```

It gives you this picture :

[image]